# 404 not found on JSF after migration tomcat to wildfly 10

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jboss, wildfly

I have a small project on tomcat, it works well, now I decided to migrate to wildfly 10. 
The deployment is ok but when I want to display my jsf (primefaces)pages, it's return me a 404 not found. I don't know what I have to do because I see any errors on the console. What's wrong, What's the problem?

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>Watchlist</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Search.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

My primefaces page which return 404 not found ( this type of return is the same for all my xhtml pages). Even when i create a simple helloWorld.xhtml page, it's return me "404 not found"  :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head>


<style>
    input[type=text] {
    color: red;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: grey;
}

fieldset {
    width: 400px;
}
</style>


</h:head> 
<body>

<h1>Test</h1> 

<h:form method="post" action="Movies.xhtml">

    <p:inputText  type="text" value="#{tshiliflixBean.m.title}" placeholder="Rechercher un film, un artiste..."/>
    <p:commandButton value="Rechercher " action="#{tshiliflixBean.ListFilmSearch()}"/>

    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.TshiliDB.movieDB</groupId>
  <artifactId>Tshiflix</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>

        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
</project>
```

My console view when, i start my wildfly server:

```
19:04:00,505 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
19:04:00,685 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
19:04:00,750 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
19:04:01,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy
19:04:01,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
19:04:01,619 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
19:04:01,625 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
19:04:01,649 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
19:04:01,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
19:04:01,664 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
19:04:01,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
19:04:01,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
19:04:01,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
19:04:01,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
19:04:01,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
19:04:01,713 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
19:04:01,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
19:04:01,800 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
19:04:01,800 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
19:04:01,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
19:04:01,815 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
19:04:01,830 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
19:04:01,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar
19:04:01,847 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
19:04:01,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
19:04:01,954 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/Users/Tshili/Documents/Library/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
19:04:01,987 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
19:04:01,989 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
19:04:02,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
19:04:02,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
19:04:02,076 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:9090
19:04:02,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/dsWatchlist]
19:04:02,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
19:04:02,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/Tshili/Documents/Library/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
19:04:02,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
19:04:02,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Tshiflix2.war" (runtime-name: "Tshiflix2.war")
19:04:02,471 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
19:04:02,471 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
19:04:02,471 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
19:04:02,480 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
19:04:04,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Watchlist
19:04:04,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Watchlist
19:04:04,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#Watchlist'
19:04:04,295 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Watchlist
    ...]
19:04:04,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Tshiflix2.war#Watchlist'
19:04:04,296 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Watchlist
    ...]
19:04:04,342 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
19:04:04,378 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
19:04:04,379 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
19:04:04,381 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
19:04:04,396 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment Tshiflix2.war
19:04:04,418 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
19:04:04,425 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
19:04:04,425 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
19:04:04,438 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
19:04:04,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'watchlistDAO' in deployment unit 'deployment "Tshiflix2.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/Tshiflix2/watchlistDAO!com.Tshiflix.DAO.WatchlistImpl
    java:app/Tshiflix2/watchlistDAO!com.Tshiflix.DAO.WatchlistImpl
    java:module/watchlistDAO!com.Tshiflix.DAO.WatchlistImpl
    java:global/Tshiflix2/watchlistDAO
    java:app/Tshiflix2/watchlistDAO
    java:module/watchlistDAO

19:04:04,502 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'watchlistDAO' in deployment unit 'deployment "Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/watchlistDAO!com.Tshiflix.DAO.WatchlistImpl
    java:app/Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/watchlistDAO!com.Tshiflix.DAO.WatchlistImpl
    java:module/watchlistDAO!com.Tshiflix.DAO.WatchlistImpl
    java:global/Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/watchlistDAO
    java:app/Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/watchlistDAO
    java:module/watchlistDAO

19:04:04,685 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:04:04,687 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:04:04,688 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:04:04,689 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
19:04:04,867 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 6.0)
19:04:04,869 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
19:04:04,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 6.0)
19:04:04,904 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: Tshiflix2.war
19:04:04,904 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900: 2.3.2 (Final)
19:04:04,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_6_0
19:04:04,943 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = Tshiflix2.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_6_0
19:04:04,944 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment Tshiflix2.war
19:04:04,944 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
19:04:05,031 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
19:04:05,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Tshiflix2.war#Watchlist'
19:04:05,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#Watchlist'
19:04:05,473 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
19:04:05,473 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
19:04:05,517 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Envers integration enabled? : true
19:04:05,517 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Envers integration enabled? : true
19:04:06,758 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '/Tshiflix2'
19:04:06,758 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '/Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
19:04:08,152 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Monitoring file:/Users/Tshili/Documents/Library/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp33c1df153414a973/content-a01220796e5c75cd/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
19:04:08,163 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
19:04:08,163 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
19:04:08,181 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /Tshiflix2
19:04:08,182 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
19:04:08,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Tshiflix2.war" (runtime-name : "Tshiflix2.war")
19:04:08,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
19:04:08,276 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
19:04:08,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
19:04:08,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 8076ms - Started 792 of 1066 services (394 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Please, paste all relevant code (html, server side Java code etc.) here and avoid using images for this.

Comment: How are you accessing the page?

Comment: How are you accessing the page? I mean the URL.

Comment: @Runcorn Now when i type  "http://localhost:9090/Tshiflix2/Search.xhtml" it's return me a blank page but i can see the source code and the http response it's 200. it's better but it's not what i'm looking for lol

Answer (score 1):

I found myself where is the problem. My web.xml wasn't good. I post the good one for somebody who will have the same issue than me

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


  <display-name>Watchlist</display-name>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/Tshiflix-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Search.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```